# High level GPU programming in C++

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

I've been looking into libraries/extensions for C++ that will allow GPU-based processing on a high level. I'm not an expert in GPU programming and I don't want to dig too deep. I have a neural network consisting of classes with virtual functions. I need a library that basically does the GPU allocation for me - on a high level. There is a guy who wrote a thesis on a system called GPU++ which does most of the GPU stuff for you. I can't find the code anywhere, just his thesis.

Does anyone know of a similar library, or does anyone have the code for GPU++? Libraries like CUDA are too low level and can't handle most of my operations (at least not without rewriting all my processes and algorithms - which I don't want to do).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The **[Thrust](http://thrust.github.io/)** library provides containers, parallel primitives and algorithms. All of this functionality is nicely wrapped up in a STL-like syntax. So, if you are familiar with STL, you can actually write entire CUDA programs using just Thrust, without having to write a single CUDA kernel. Have a look at the simple examples in the **[Quick Start Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/index.html#axzz4K9OPc1Tr)** to see the kind of high-level programs you can write using Thrust.

Answer (score 62):

There are many high-level libraries dedicated to GPGPU programming. Since they rely on CUDA and/or OpenCL, they have to be chosen wisely (a CUDA-based program will not run on AMD's GPUs, unless it goes through a pre-processing step with projects such as [**gpuocelot**](http://code.google.com/p/gpuocelot/)).

### CUDA

You can find some examples of CUDA libraries on the NVIDIA [website](https://developer.nvidia.com/technologies/Libraries).

- [**Thrust**](http://thrust.github.io/): the official description speaks for itself

> Thrust is a parallel algorithms library which resembles the C++ Standard
>   Template Library (STL). Thrust's high-level interface greatly enhances
>   programmer productivity while enabling performance portability between
>   GPUs and multicore CPUs. Interoperability with established
>   technologies (such as CUDA, TBB, and OpenMP) facilitates integration
>   with existing software.

As [@Ashwin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16478427/1043187) pointed out, the STL-like syntax of Thrust makes it a widely chosen library when developing CUDA programs. A quick look at the examples shows the kind of code you will be writing if you decide to use this library. NVIDIA's website presents the [key features](https://developer.nvidia.com/thrust) of this library. A [video presentation](http://nvidia.fullviewmedia.com/gtc2012/0515-A3-S0602.html) (from GTC 2012) is also available.

- [**CUB**](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/): the official description tells us:

> CUB provides state-of-the-art, reusable software components for every layer of the CUDA programming mode. It is a flexible library of cooperative threadblock primitives and other utilities for CUDA kernel programming.

It provides device-wide, block-wide and warp-wide parallel primitives such as parallel sort, prefix scan, reduction, histogram etc.

It is open-source and available on [GitHub](https://github.com/NVlabs/cub). It is not high-level from an implementation point of view (you develop in CUDA kernels), but provides high-level algorithms and routines.

- [**mshadow**](https://github.com/tqchen/mshadow): lightweight CPU/GPU matrix/tensor template library in C++/CUDA.

This library is mostly used for machine learning, and relies on [expression templates](https://github.com/tqchen/mshadow/wiki/Expression%20Template).

- [**Eigen**](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/): support for CUDA with a new Tensor class have been [added in version 3.3](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=3.3#Experimental_CUDA_support). It is used by Google in [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/), and is still experimental.

> Starting from Eigen 3.3, it is now possible to use Eigen's objects and algorithms within CUDA kernels. However, only a subset of features are supported to make sure that no dynamic allocation is triggered within a CUDA kernel.

### OpenCL

Note that [OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) does more than GPGPU computing, since it supports heterogeneous platforms (multi-core CPUs, GPUs etc.).

- [**OpenACC**](http://www.openacc-standard.org): this project provides OpenMP-like support for GPGPU. A large part of the programming is done implicitly by the compiler and the run-time API. You can find a [sample code](http://www.openacc.org/sites/default/files/Heat-Conduction-C--Sample-V2.pdf) on their website.

> The OpenACC Application Program Interface describes a collection of
>   compiler directives to specify loops and regions of code in standard
>   C, C++ and Fortran to be offloaded from a host CPU to an attached
>   accelerator, providing portability across operating systems, host CPUs
>   and accelerators.

- [**Bolt**](https://github.com/HSA-Libraries/Bolt): open-source library with STL-like interface.

> Bolt is a C++ template library optimized for heterogeneous computing.
>   Bolt is designed to provide high-performance library implementations
>   for common algorithms such as scan, reduce, transform, and sort. The
>   Bolt interface was modeled on the C++ Standard Template Library (STL).
>   Developers familiar with the STL will recognize many of the Bolt APIs
>   and customization techniques.

- [**Boost.Compute**](http://boostorg.github.io/compute/): as [@Kyle Lutz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16441065/1043187) said, Boost.Compute provides a STL-like interface for OpenCL. Note that this is not an official Boost library (yet).
- [**SkelCL**](http://skelcl.uni-muenster.de/) "is a library providing high-level abstractions for alleviated programming of modern parallel heterogeneous systems". This library relies on [skeleton programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeleton_%28computer_programming%29), and you can find more information in their [research papers](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=6008967).

### CUDA + OpenCL

- [**ArrayFire**](http://arrayfire.com) is an open-source (used to be proprietary) GPGPU programming library. They first targeted CUDA, but now support OpenCL as well. You can check the [examples](http://arrayfire.org/docs/examples.htm) available online. NVIDIA's website provides a [good summary](https://developer.nvidia.com/accelereyes-arrayfire) of its key features.

### Complementary information

Although this is not really in the scope of this question, there is also the same kind of support for other programming languages:

- **Python**: [**PyCUDA**](https://developer.nvidia.com/pycuda) for CUDA, [**Clyther**](http://srossross.github.io/Clyther/) and [**PyOpenCL**](http://mathema.tician.de/software/pyopencl) for OpenCL. There is a [dedicated StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957554/python-gpu-programming) for this.
- **Java**: [**JCuda**](http://www.jcuda.org/) for CUDA, and for OpenCL, you can check this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633483/best-approach-for-gpgpu-cuda-opencl-in-java).
- **JavaScript**: [**GPU.JS**](https://gpu.rocks/) for WebGl.

If you need to do linear algebra (for instance) or other specific operations, dedicated math libraries are also available for CUDA and OpenCL (e.g. [**ViennaCL**](http://viennacl.sourceforge.net/viennacl-about.html), [**CUBLAS**](https://developer.nvidia.com/cublas), [**MAGMA**](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/magma/index.html) etc.).

Also note that using these libraries does not prevent you from doing some low-level operations if you need to do some very specific computation.

Finally, we can mention the future of the C++ standard library. There has been extensive work to add parallelism support. This is [still a technical specification](https://github.com/cplusplus/parallelism-ts), and GPUs are not explicitely mentioned AFAIK (although NVIDIA's Jared Hoberock, developer of Thrust, is directly involved), but the will to make this a reality is definitely there.

Comment: I used Eigen to invert large matrices and only runs 2x faster than using a one thread code

Comment: At the time of this writing, it looks like ArrayFire is one of the few libraries still being maintained, and it seems to be the most versatile.

Comment: This needs to be updated with NVIDIA [MatX](https://github.com/NVIDIA/MatX) as well as all of the new AMD ROCM alternatives like [rocThrust](https://github.com/ROCmSoftwarePlatform/rocThrust). With Intel GPGPUs on the Horizon, one might even include OneAPI stuff. Also there is SYCL and Kokkos trying to generally bring more portability.

Answer (score 15):

Take a look at [Boost.Compute](http://boostorg.github.io/compute/). It provides a high-level, STL-like interface including containers like [`vector<T>`](http://boostorg.github.io/compute/boost/compute/vector.html) and algorithms like [`transform()`](http://boostorg.github.io/compute/boost/compute/transform.html) and [`sort()`](http://boostorg.github.io/compute/boost/compute/sort.html).

It's built on [OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) allowing it to run on most modern GPUs and CPUs including those by NVIDIA, AMD, and Intel.

Answer (score 2):

Another high level library is [VexCL](https://github.com/ddemidov/vexcl) -- a vector expression template library for OpenCL. It provides intuitive notation for vector operations and is available under MIT license.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for higher-dimensional containers and the ability to pass and manipulate these containers in kernel code, I've spent the last few years developing the [ecuda](https://github.com/BaderLab/ecuda) API to assist in my own scientific research projects (so it's been put through the paces).  Hopefully it can fill a needed niche.  A brief example of how it can be used (C++11 features are used here, but ecuda will work fine with pre-C++11 compilers):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <ecuda/ecuda.hpp>

// kernel function
__global__
void calcColumnSums(
  typename ecuda::matrix<double>::const_kernel_argument mat,
  typename ecuda::vector<double>::kernel_argument vec
)
{
    const std::size_t t = threadIdx.x;
    auto col = mat.get_column(t);
    vec[t] = ecuda::accumulate( col.begin(), col.end(), static_cast<double>(0) );
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{

    // allocate 1000x1000 hardware-aligned device memory matrix
    ecuda::matrix<double> deviceMatrix( 1000, 1000 );

    // generate random values row-by-row and copy to matrix
    std::vector<double> hostRow( 1000 );
    for( std::size_t i = 0; i < 1000; ++i ) {
        for( double& x : hostRow ) x = static_cast<double>(rand())/static_cast<double>(RAND_MAX);
        ecuda::copy( hostRow.begin(), hostRow.end(), deviceMatrix[i].begin() );
    }

    // allocate device memory for column sums
    ecuda::vector<double> deviceSums( 1000 );

    CUDA_CALL_KERNEL_AND_WAIT(
        calcColumnSums<<<1,1000>>>( deviceMatrix, deviceSums )
    );

    // copy columns sums to host and print
    std::vector<double> hostSums( 1000 );
    ecuda::copy( deviceSums.begin(), deviceSums.end(), hostSums.begin() );

    std::cout << "SUMS =";
    for( const double& x : hostSums ) std::cout << " " << std::fixed << x;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;

}
```

I wrote it to be as an intuitive as possible (usually as simple as replacing std:: with ecuda::).  If you know STL, then ecuda should do what you'd logically expect a CUDA-based C++ extension to do.

Comment: ecuda avoids memory transfer in following call to functions?. What is the performance?. Does it hides the complex memory allocation and transfers?

Answer (score 1):

The cpp-opencl project provides a way to make programming GPUs easy for the developer. It allows you to implement data parallelism on a GPU directly in C++ instead of using OpenCL.

Please see http://dimitri-christodoulou.blogspot.com/2014/02/implement-data-parallelism-on-gpu.html

And the source code: https://github.com/dimitrs/cpp-opencl

See the example below. The code in the parallel_for_each lambda function is executed on the GPU, and all the rest is executed on the CPU. More specifically, the “square” function is executed both on the CPU (via a call to std::transform) and the GPU (via a call to compute::parallel_for_each).

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ParallelForEach.h"

template<class T> 
T square(T x)  
{
    return x * x;
}

void func() {
  std::vector<int> In {1,2,3,4,5,6};
  std::vector<int> OutGpu(6);
  std::vector<int> OutCpu(6);

  compute::parallel_for_each(In.begin(), In.end(), OutGpu.begin(), [](int x){
      return square(x);
  });


  std::transform(In.begin(), In.end(), OutCpu.begin(), [](int x) {
    return square(x);
  });

  // 
  // Do something with OutCpu and OutGpu …..........

  //

}

int main() {
  func();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The new [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/) version 4 now includes accelerator offload support.

AFAIK GPUs are considered as accelerators.

Answer (score 0):

C++ AMP is The answer you are looking for.

Comment: Looking for something cross-platform. AMP seems to Windows specific.

Comment: Microsoft & AMD released a C++ AMP "with linux support". Is C++AMP a higher level library that hides the Opencl or it is a different solution?